# Kafka Producer to publish messages from XML file to Kafka Topic

Tags: java, xml, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a use case "XML file ==> Kafka Topic ==> Build REST API to query" the data from kafka Topics. I am familiar with converting the data to Avro format and write to kafka topic.

Could you please suggest how to publish the XML?

File data contains multiple records for kafka topic and when consuming the data from kafka topics, how to access from Rest API?

I also tried to publish with kafka-console-producer but key being populated as NULL for each line of xml file instead of a XML record.

code looks like below.

```
producer.sendMessage(linenum, line);

public static final String fileName = "testfolder/memberdetails.xml";

public void sendMessage(String key, String value) {

            producer.send(
                    new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, key, value))

            System.out.println("Sent message: (" + key + ", " + value + ")");
        } 
}
```

Comment: You need to actually parse the xml... Not clear what good sending single lines (for example, a single xml tag) will get you

Answer (score 2):

1. Ingest the XML files with Kafka Connect and the [XML transformation](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml)
2. Serve the data from the Kafka topic using the open-source [Confluent REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html) (available either as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/), or [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest))

Comment: hanks Robin. I am importing the maven project from kafka-connect-transform-xml example. But the below imports are unable to find. Do we have a maven dependency information for the below imports? import com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.BaseTransformation; import com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.utils.config.Description; import com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.utils.config.DocumentationTip; import com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.utils.config.Title; import com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.xml.Connectable;

Comment: @Srinivas That plugin is meant to be used with the Kafka Connect framework. You wouldnt import those for a producer api, and you instead download the transformer, https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml/releases  Then you still need a way to get your file into the Connect API data format